# Define calculator?

Tags: javascript

How do I define calculator?

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: calculator is not defined
  at HTMLButtonElement.onclick
```

When I try to run the code in a web browser, I never get an answer. I can write in the boxes, and click the buttons, but I never get a result.

```js
var Calculator = function(inp1,inp2,reslt) {
    this.valinp1 = inp1;
    this.valinp2 = inp2;
    this.result = reslt;
    if (!Calculator.prototype.sum) {
      calculator.prototype.sum = function() {
        var value1 = Number(this.valinp1.value),
            value2 = Number(this.valinp2.value);

            this.result.innerHTML =
             (!/[0-9]/.test(String(value1)) || !/[0-9]/.test(String(value1)))
             : (value1 + value2);
        };
```

```html
<input id="v1" type="text" style="width:5em;"/>
<button onclick="calculator.sum();">+</button>
<button onclick="calculator.multiply();">*</button>
<button onclick="calculator.div();">/</button>
<button onclick="calculator.mod();">%</button>
<input id="v2" type="text" style="width:5em;"/>
<span id="result"> </span>
```

Comment: `calculator.prototype.` is causing issue. Notice `C` and not `c`

Comment: case sensitivity. `var Calculator` is in caps

Comment: Thank you! But I still cannot get it to work?